# Error when running Karaf in ODL

Tags: java, karaf, mininet, sdn, opendaylight

A few minutes after initiating Karaf, I always receive this error. Cant figure out what the impact of this is or how to fix it:

```
opendaylight-user@root>Exception in thread "config-pusher" java.lang.SecurityException: Insufficient roles/credentials for operation
    at org.apache.karaf.management.KarafMBeanServerGuard.handleInvoke(KarafMBeanServerGuard.java:289)
    at org.apache.karaf.management.KarafMBeanServerGuard.invoke(KarafMBeanServerGuard.java:85)
    at org.apache.karaf.management.boot.KarafMBeanServerBuilder$MBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(KarafMBeanServerBuilder.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$InvokeHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:150)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:167)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.beginConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.config.util.ConfigRegistryJMXClient.beginConfig(ConfigRegistryJMXClient.java:96)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.confignetconfconnector.transactions.TransactionProvider.getTestTransaction(TransactionProvider.java:120)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.confignetconfconnector.operations.editconfig.EditConfig.test(EditConfig.java:109)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.confignetconfconnector.operations.editconfig.EditConfig.executeTests(EditConfig.java:96)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.confignetconfconnector.operations.editconfig.EditConfig.getResponseInternal(EditConfig.java:75)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.confignetconfconnector.operations.editconfig.EditConfig.handleWithNoSubsequentOperations(EditConfig.java:308)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.util.mapping.AbstractLastNetconfOperation.handle(AbstractLastNetconfOperation.java:33)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.util.mapping.AbstractNetconfOperation.handle(AbstractNetconfOperation.java:100)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.ConfigPusherImpl.sendRequestGetResponseCheckIsOK(ConfigPusherImpl.java:342)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.ConfigPusherImpl.pushConfig(ConfigPusherImpl.java:293)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.ConfigPusherImpl.pushConfigWithConflictingVersionRetries(ConfigPusherImpl.java:135)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.ConfigPusherImpl.internalPushConfigs(ConfigPusherImpl.java:103)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.ConfigPusherImpl.process(ConfigPusherImpl.java:76)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.netconf.persist.impl.osgi.ConfigPersisterActivator$InnerCustomizer$1.run(ConfigPersisterActivator.java:181)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has any one else experienced this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Karaf 3.0.1 has a known JMX bug that should be fixed in 3.0.2… if you don’t get your bin/karaf from "controller/opendaylight/distributions/opendaylight-karaf-resources" you will get this exception.

Edit this file:

> karaf/target/assembly/system/org/opendaylight/controller/karaf-parent/1.5.3-SNAPSHOT/karaf-parent-1.5.3-SNAPSHOT.pom

And set **ignorePermissions** tag **true**.

References: 
https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/controller-dev/2014-September/006551.html
https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/controller-dev/2014-September/006552.html